# php+mysql: Подсчитать количество вхождений каждого символа в базе

Tags: php, mysql

Есть таблица БД с текстовыми полями ~30млн. записей UTF-8.

Необходимо подсчитать количество вхождений каждого символа во всей базе.

Результат - что-то вроде:

А - 235235434 шт.

Б - 23568285 шт.

....
и т.д.

Comment: Вытащить все строки и в цикле посчитать. Если хотите побыстрее, то используйте многопоточность в php.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT c.letter, SUM(LENGTH(t.field) - LENGTH(REPLACE(t.field, c.letter, ''))) `count`
FROM table t, (SELECT 'A' letter
               UNION
               SELECT 'B'
               UNION
               -- 
               SELECT 'ю'
               UNION
               SELECT 'я'
              ) с
GROUP BY c.letter
```

Для генерации таблицы символов (она необходима!) можно использовать любой другой способ. И даже создать такую таблицу (это вообще самый правильный вариант).

Если в исходной таблице несколько полей и надо посчитать по отдельности - добавить соотв. количество `SUM()` в выходной набор. А если надо посчитать вместе - заменить `field` на `CONCAT(field1, field2, ...)`.

Comment: спасибо большое. А если неизвестно какие символы встречаются?

Comment: *А если неизвестно какие символы встречаются?* Считай все возможные. Или сперва пройди по всем записям посимвольно и собери в таблицу все встречающиеся вообще символы. Вот только ждать, пока их наберётся, забахаешься...

Comment: Вот пример на коленке ежели: [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=914f4fc8b2b29cd533beddaf994c0f88). Проблемы с тем, что пробел и пустая строка с точки зрения bin одно и то же, решай сам.